# Java PubMed blocks url requests

Tags: java, block, http-request, pubmed

I have some code that accesses articles in PubMed and parses some information from each XML. The program works fine on my computer, but needs a lot of time to finish. So when i run it on a unix machine especially for this kind of things, every request i make is blocked. There is a limit to how many can be made each minute before the machine considers it a virus, but that is not the problem, as all the requests are blocked. I checked and this happens only with requests at the PubMed site.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I use jsoup for connection. Running wget with ProcessBuilder from my program works without getting blocked but then efficiency becomes an issue because the output from wget can only be read with `while(br.readline() != null)` and this ads a lot of run time.

Comment: What do you mean "Blocked"?  Do you mean the IO is blocking, or that the system causes an error or something saying you have reached some limits.  Theoretically, on a *nix machine, you have 'ulimits', which controls certain things like how many files you can have open at once.  In *nix, everything is a file, including sockets.

Comment: The blocking is not directly visible. Instead of retrieving the correct HTML I always get one that says I have been blocked due to misuse. The program continues like nothing has happened but when it tries to parse the HTML it does not find what it is supposed to.

Comment: That has nothing to do with your unix box, then.  That sounds like the remote server has some sort of throttle.  Most public websites do to prevent DoS attacks.

Comment: If this is the case then it would not work on my computer, right?

Comment: If that's the case, the solution is not to bombard the remote host with requests, but rather figure out what their threshold is, and stay just under that.  Most web services publish something in their docs indicating what their request thresholds are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing pubmed webpage you can try to connect via other API, dedicated to retrieving pubmed data, like RESTful Web Service: http://europepmc.org/RestfulWebService.
It allows you to get all the data you need in xml format and I think that there is no limit for number of queries.

For instance if you want to get all the information about article with `pubmed_id=9481671`, you need to access webpage: http://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search/resulttype=core&query=ext_id:9481671.

Comment: I tried that and it works! Thanks so much. Do you know where i can see the query limit? Don't want to get blocked from there also

Comment: @MariosD.Lokas: Your're welcome. I haven't seen any information about limits. I queried for 1 500 different articles and didn't have any problems (and I would expect any - I use few ebi interfaces and never encountered problems with query limits). However if you think this could be an issue, you can download full db (http://europepmc.org/ftp/oa/) and parse it manually. But this solution have one drawback: from time to time you will have to download again all files to keep your data up to date.

Comment: I want to query over 500.000 articles. I believe i have to send an email and ask. Again, thanks a lot for your help